# My ag-grid doesnt show up any Data

Tags: javascript, json, angular, ag-grid

Im fairly new to Angular/Typescript. Im kinda learning and developing at the same time. Im trying to build a grid with data loaded from a Json file and Im having some issues with showing my Data. I'd love if you guys could point to my error, cuz my code compiles with no errors and Im kinda helpless at the moment.

Ill provide my code below.
Thanks in advance.

my-grid-application.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-grid-application',
  templateUrl: './my-grid-application.component.html'
})
export class MyGridApplicationComponent {
  private gridOptions: GridOptions;
  things:Things[];

  getThings(){
    this.myGridApplicationService.getThings().subscribe( things => 
this.things = things)
  }

constructor( private myGridApplicationService: MyGridApplicationService) {
    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    var gridOptions = {
        onGridReady: function() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.things);
        }
    }
    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: "ID",
            field: "id",
            width: 100
        },
        {
            headerName: "Value",
            field: "value",
            cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
            width: 100
        },

    ]; 
  } 
}
```

my-grid-application.service.ts

```
export class Things{

}

@Injectable()
export class MyGridApplicationService {
  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getThings(){
    return this.http.get('src/assets/data.json')
        .map((response:Response)=> <Things[]>response.json().data)
  }
}
```

data.json

```
{
"data" :[
    {
        "id": "red",
        "value": "#f00"
    },
    {
        "id": "green",
        "value": "#0f0"
    }
]
}
```

my-grid-application.component.html

```
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 200px;" class="ag-
theme-fresh"
           [gridOptions]="gridOptions">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an Ag-Grid expert, but why are you re-declaring gridOptions with **var gridOptions** in the constructor. This is the obvious mistake and should be corrected:

```
this.gridOptions = {
    onGridReady: function() {
        this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.things);
    }
}
```

because that is the property you're accessing in the template.

Check this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/alobban/Ag-Grid-Sample) from my [Github](https://github.com/alobban/Ag-Grid-Sample)

```
//MyGridApplication
constructor( private myGridApplicationService: MyGridApplicationService) {
    myGridApplicationService.getThings()
        .subscribe( things => this.things = things);

    this.gridOptions = <GridOptions>{};
    this.gridOptions = {
        onGridReady: () => {
            this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.things);
        }
    };

    this.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {
            headerName: "ID",
            field: "id",
            width: 100
        },
        {
            headerName: "Value",
            field: "value",
            cellRendererFramework: RedComponentComponent,
            width: 100
        },

    ]; 
}
```

Comment: The var gridOptions needs to be defined else he wont be able to recognise the .api method to set up the data. Thanks for the answer tho

Comment: The hting is that I dont want the data raw coded on a component, I just want to load it from a server/json file, because I have thousands of rows to add to my grid.

Comment: I understand your issue now, so when you injected the service, myGridApplicationService, if you want to get the information, you either copy the code in your getThings() method into the constructor or call get things from your constructor before you start to use it. See code block in Answer

Comment: @VascoOliveira you’re welcome! Glad I was of use while trying to learn this product as well.

Answer (score 0):

When onGridReady() is fired, "this.things" is not populated yet.
try this:

```
var gridOptions = {
    rowData: this.things
}
```

Comment: That didn't work for me. it keep just showing "Loading" on my grid. Thanks tho

Comment: where do you call getThings()? try calling it inside in the constructor.

Comment: can you post the content of "my-grid-application.component.html" ?